# Updating or Resetting ng-model binding to new attribute

Tags: angularjs, compilation, angular-ngmodel

I have updated the binding for the ng-model to a new attribute in the scope. I have to compile the template to update the angular bindings.

```
directive('reset', function($compile) {
  return {
      restrict: "A",
      link: function(scope, element, attribute) {
          console.log('inside reset directive');
          scope.updateBinding = function() {
            element.children().eq(0).attr({'ng-model': 'testobj.two'});
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
          }      
      }
  };
});
```

But after doing so any update to on the new ng-model attribute updates the old attribute as well. And this happens only after i do a compile.
Without compile things work perfectly.

Why is bindings behaving this way after doing compile.

[Here is a plunkr for the same.](http://plnkr.co/edit/OxmnrAMQPrcqFrvWzQ3a)